# How to make conditions for choice in an R code

Tags: r

I created a dataframe which has a column of alternatives and the others are rankings of some methods. After that I did spearman correlation to compare `Method 2, 3 and 4` with `Method 1`, and got results from that. However, now I would like to create a variable called `output` that does the following: choose the ranking of the method that has the highest correlation with the `Method1`.

```
df<-structure(list(Alternatives = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    METHOD1 = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L),  METHOD2 = c(1L, 
    8L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L),  METHOD3 = c(1L, 10L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L),  METHOD4 = c(1, 9, 7, 6, 10, 
    8, 5, 4, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

> df
   Alternatives METHOD1 METHOD2 METHOD3 METHOD4
1             3       1       1       1       1
2             4      10       8      10       9
3             5       7       7       7       7
4             6       8       6       8       6
5             7       9      10       9      10
6             8       6       9       6       8
7             9       5       4       4       5
8            10       3       3       2       4
9            11       4       2       3       3
10           12       2       5       5       2

Sp<- df %>%
    summarise(across(METHOD2:METHOD4,  ~cor.test(., METHOD1, method = "spearman")$estimate))

 > Sp
    METHOD2   METHOD3   METHOD4
1 0.8060606 0.9272727 0.9272727
```

Comment: What is your desired form of output in that? Just the name of the 'METHOD' will be sufficient?

Comment: No, I would like to show the ranking of the method with the highest correlation. The ranking is what was defined in `df` database.

Comment: What if there are two maximum values? What would you do in that case? Show both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**

Considering you'll have more than one 'METHOD' having the highest correlation. You can do this:

**Procedure**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarise(across(METHOD2:METHOD4,  ~cor.test(., METHOD1, method = "spearman")$estimate)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('METHOD')) %>%
  slice_max(value) %>%
  pull(name)-> selected_method

df[(colnames(df) %in% c(selected_method))]
```

**Output**

```
 METHOD3 METHOD4
1        1       1
2       10       9
3        7       7
4        8       6
5        9      10
6        6       8
7        4       5
8        2       4
9        3       3
10       5       2
```

**Case 2**

You need only 1 'METHOD'

**Procedure**

```
df %>%
  summarise(across(METHOD2:METHOD4,  ~cor.test(., METHOD1, method = "spearman")$estimate)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('METHOD')) %>%
  slice_max(value) %>%
  slice_head(n=1) %>%
  pull(name)-> selected_method

df[(colnames(df) %in% c(selected_method))]
```

**Output**

```
METHOD3
1        1
2       10
3        7
4        8
5        9
6        6
7        4
8        2
9        3
10       5
```